# How to calculate REM for type?

Tags: css

How do I convert PX into REM for my type? I've read Jonathan Snook's article about using REM, but he was using font-size:62.5%, which defaults to your font size to 10px (for easier calculating). How would I convert my PX units into REM if I was to use 100%, 75%, and so forth?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`Target Size / Base Size = Value`

Since we can assume that browsers use 16px as default (after all, that's what Jonathan Snook did to assume that 62.5% is 10px), then your Base is 16. If you want 32px, then `32 / 16 = 2`, want 40px then `40 / 16 = 2.5`, want 24 then `24 / 16 = 1.5`.

The same goes for 75%... Determine what 75% is (it's 12) and perform the same calculation. If you want 32px, then `32 / 12 = 2.666`, want 40px then `40 / 12 = 3.333`, want 24 then `24 / 12 = 2`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I did have another question. When would you use REM over PX, EM and %?

Comment: @jeff If you have another question, [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question. But someone already asked [the difference between `em` and `rem`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13941275/383793).

Comment: Already did... about a year ago. Great comment. Thanks it help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

if u just add this code to your style file

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

it will convert 1 rem=10px. Now you will be working 10px base. So

```
body {
  font-size: 1.6 rem;
}
```

u will have font size 1.6*10=16 px.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the OP, but still very useful.  Thanks :)

Comment: although it's a solution, but it will impact all third-party libraries and extension that you use on that page