# SASS: increasing font size increases size of everything

Tags: css, sass

I'm building a react app using SASS. All my font-sizes, image sizes, and margins are in em units.
I added this to my SASS file so that when displaying content at 1920px width resolution or greater, the font size is increased by 1.25.

```
$base-font-size: 1em;

body {
font-family: Gilroy, sans-serif;
font-size: $base-font-size;

    @media (min-width: 1920px){
        font-size: $base-font-size*1.25;
    }
}
```

However, upon doing this, all elements that are sized in em units become enlarged (fonts and images). The font is enlarging just fine but images are getting enlarged as well (which is not what I'm after). That's despite applying the property to font-size only

Comment: em is relative to base font size. use rem instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941275/how-does-rem-differ-from-em-in-css#:~:text=While%20em%20is%20relative%20to,across%20the%20entire%20page%20easily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does rem differ from em in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941275/how-does-rem-differ-from-em-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below link

https://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/

`Em` is causing problems here because it's relative to ancestor's font size.

`Rem` might be a good alternative for You because it's related to root / html font size

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in the question (I'll edit it). The issue isn't with the font size. The enlarge just fine with both rem and em. The problem here is that the images are enlarging too even though I'm only applying the property to font-size.

Comment: have you tried applying sizes for those images using rem ? :)

Comment: yes, it did not work. The only solution I know so far is to give sizes to images in pixels and not em

Comment: maybe add a font size to your <html> element and than, in Your media queries realted to text elements change the font size using rems and it will scale relatively to the base / html font size and the images will not be modified