# can I use em and rem for things other than font-size?

Tags: html, css

> To recap, the em unit means "my parent element's font-size" in the
> case of typography. The `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` with a class of
> ems take their sizing from their parent. So each successive level of
> nesting gets progressively larger, as each has its font size set to
> 1.3em — 1.3 times its parent's font size.
>
> To recap, the rem unit means "The root element's font-size". (rem
> stands for "root em".) The `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` with a class
> of rems take their sizing from the root element (`<html>`). This means
> that each successive level of nesting does not keep getting larger.

This is the explanation that Mozilla provides.

I can see that in my places of other people's code, they have `padding: 1.5rem`.  It means that `rem` and `em` are not coupled to font-size at all.  Is that right ?

**Question 1)** So, if I set `padding:1.5rem` on an element, what size will it have ? what does it look at so that it can figure out its own padding size ?

**Question 2)** What about `padding:1.5em` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does rem differ from em in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941275/how-does-rem-differ-from-em-in-css)

Comment: "It means that rem and em are not coupled to font-size at all. Is that right ?" No, that is not right. Those sizes are coupled to the font size specified. `rem` is coupled to the font size specified at the root element, whereas `em` is coupled to the font size calculated for the specific element selected by the selector of the rule it's on.

Comment: @HereticMonkey than, if I have `padding:1.5rem`, it looks at the font-size of the root element(html) and sets padding as 1.5 * font-size of html ?

Comment: Yes, @GiorgiLagidze, exactly that. So, if your `rem` was `16px`, then `padding: 1.5rem` would be the same as `padding: 24px`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use em and rem for any measure of length.

*Question 1) So, if I set padding:1.5rem on an element, what size will it have? what does it look at so that it can figure out its own padding size ?*

If the padding of an element is 1.5rem, it will have a padding length of 1.5 times the font size of the html element. In the example below, the outer box has a padding of 1.5x or 15px, and the inner box is 2x or 20px.

```css
html{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.p,.c{
  border: solid 1px #f00;
}

.p{
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.c{
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='p'>
  <div class='c'></div>
</div>
```

Question 2) What about padding:1.5em ?

An element with 1.5em padding will take 1.5x the font-size of the nearest parent (including self) with a font size set. So if you set the font size of the outer box from the previous example to 8px, it will have 1.5x or 12px of padding, and the inner element will have 2x or 16px padding.

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.p,
.c {
  border: solid 1px #f00;
}

.p {
  font-size: 8px;
  padding: 1.5em;
}

.c {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class='p'>
  <div class='c'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer1: So if you set `padding:1.5rem` , it will take the size according to root font size of root HTML that is 24px. (1rem is 16px by default)

It will further set the padding space according to given value and multiplies it by the font size of root element(HTML).

Answer2: And it causes same with **em** , it will multiplies the em's value according to the font size given.
By default it is 12px for 1em.  So if you set `paddind:1.5em` it will add a padding space of 16px.

May this helps.

**Note:** `em to px` and `rem to px` values may vary accordingly.