# rem in Dev Console, how to "convert" it to px?

Tags: html, css

I'm inspecting a website via Chrome and its Dev Tools. When i inspect an element, there is just the a rem property for the font-size.

**I want to "translate" this to Pixel.**

> Is there a way? When not, why?

Comment: Did you check the "computed" tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate REM for type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352783/how-to-calculate-rem-for-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rem` is a proportion of the font size of the root element (`html` in an HTML document).

If you know what the font size (in pixels) of that element is, then you can just multiple by the `rem` value.

If you don't know (because, for example, it isn't explicitly specified and is using the users' preferences) then you can't.

Your browser's developer tools will probably compute the value for you (wherever they displayed the computed values of your stylesheets) but they will be using whatever value you have configured for your default font size. Other people may have something different.

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
getComputedStyle(theElement).fontSize;
```

And if you want to convert an arbitrary number in rem to pixels:

```
function rem2px(rem) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.style.width = '1000rem';
    var factor = el.clientWidth / 1000;
    document.body.removeChild(el);
    return rem * factor;
}
```

<sup>(I use `1000` in order to have more precision.)</sup>