# content overlapping with flexbox header - how to avoid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

CSS styles for my menu bar

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    background: #d777ea; /*light purple*/
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
header > nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    list-style: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
header > nav > ul > li {
    margin: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
header > nav > ul > li:hover {
    background: #aa64e0; /*dark purple*/
}
header > nav > ul > li > ul {
    /* dropdown */
    position: absolute;
    background: #76a1e8; /*light blue*/
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header > nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    /* dropdown */

    display: block;
    width: 220px;

}
header > nav > ul > li > a {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

}
header > nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
}
header > nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
}
header > nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover {
    background: blue;
}
header > nav > ul > li > a > i {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
input {
    padding: .25rem;
    width: 100px;
}
input:invalid {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
header > nav > ul > li > ul > li > input:invalid + button {
    background: red;
    cursor: not-allowed;

}
button {
    padding: .25rem;
}
```

HTML header and an image

```
<header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Teams<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="preset-id" data-schoolid=13318>Huron</a> </li>
                <li><a class="preset-id" data-schoolid=99999>Pioneer</a></li>
                <li>
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="100000" class="custom-id-value" placeholder="School ID #" required>
                    <button class="custom-id"> Go </button>
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="show-calendar">Calendar</a></li>

        <li><a class="show-athletes">Athletes</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>
    <image src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg"></image>
</main>
```

When it shows up,

The content is on top of the header bar. Is there some way to avoid this? and have the content displayed below? When the dropdown is activated, I don't want the content below it to move though.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g870xy3d/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a margin top in the `main` tag with the height of the header. Also add top:0 to the header:

```
header{
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
  background: #d777ea; /*light purple*/
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

main{
   margin-top: 57px;
}
```

Comment: how do you know the margin height?

Comment: Total element height = height + top padding + bottom padding + top border + bottom border + top margin + bottom margin

Comment: what would the calculation for that be?

Comment: height = 25px (It depends of the content) + 16px + 16px + 0 + 0 + 0 +0. To check how it is calculated the rem measure check this answerd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352783/how-to-calculate-rem-for-type